# The width must be equal to the height of the block

Tags: html, css

At the moment there is a variation of height versus width - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ey16na5x/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aspect-ratio-1 {
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* (value height = value width) = 1 * 100% = 100%  */
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
}

.aspect-ratio-1-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="aspect-ratio-1">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-inner"></div>
</div>
```

How to make the vertical resize width automatically change and equal the height of the block (If possible on css)?

Thank you I will be glad to any help!

Comment: @web-tiki Thank you so much. Was inattentive

Comment: You are welcome @Dmitriy :)